Power Automate Flow runs infinitely when triggered by the word "one"
I'm experiencing an issue with my Power Automate Flow where it gets stuck in an infinite loop or responds to any word, (even if it's not part of the trigger words array) when the trigger word "one" is used.
Here's my current setup:
I have a trigger set up to listen for specific words in an incoming message (e.g., "one", "reject", "RTMate").
When the trigger word is detected, the flow is supposed to perform a series of actions.
However, when the word "one" is used, the flow goes into an infinite loop, repeating the actions indefinitely. Moreover, it also responds to any word, even if it's not part of the trigger words array.
What I've tried:
To resolve this issue, I've attempted the following:
I've tried setting a trigger condition for the trigger word step to ensure that the flow only runs when the exact word "one" is used.
I've added "one" in a separate condition to isolate the issue and see if it's specific to this word.
I've changed the trigger words from an array to a string, thinking that it might be a formatting issue.
Despite these efforts, the problem persists. I'm expecting the flow to only respond to the specific trigger words and not get stuck in an infinite loop. Has anyone else encountered this problem or have any suggestions on how to fix it?
Below is the flow
1
2
3
4
When the word "one" ins in the list the flow runs for any word in the chat like below sample
NB: the flow glitches with "one, on, 1" any of them make the flow glitch, but they are essential for the flow
Keywords
5
6
1- Successful Flow (trigger word is "Hello" which is not part of the trigger words list)
7
2- Failed Flow (flow was trying to trigger itself again and failed as it didn't manage to get the mention token of itself)
8

Your description is not full. It is hard to understand the automated process as well as where specifically you have "infinite loop". Please provide more details, if possible.
From the first perspective, the place for an infinite loop here can be if you answer the message with "one" or another trigger words - which retriggers the flow.
Review the answer message and debug what you have in "Msg content".

If you find my answer useful - please vote for it or mark as "Accepted".

Hi melicom, sorry for the inconvenience just updated the post with everything and added more screenshots
